# Change the default padding character in Java printf?

Tags: java, printf

If we do `System.out.printf("%10s", "1");` by default, the space characters will be added to fill in 10, right? Is there a way to change this?

I know, you can add `0`, by specifying `0` before the `s`, but does `printf` support anything else?

Comment: Padding with 0 is only supported for numeric types. It will not work with `s`, but it will, for example, with `d`: `System.out.printf("%010d", 1);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope.  Space is hard-coded.  Here's the snippet of java.util.Formatter source even:

```
private String justify(String s) {
    if (width == -1)
    return s;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean pad = f.contains(Flags.LEFT_JUSTIFY);
    int sp = width - s.length();
    if (!pad)
    for (int i = 0; i < sp; i++) sb.append(' ');
    sb.append(s);
    if (pad)
    for (int i = 0; i < sp; i++) sb.append(' ');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you're looking to get a different padding you could do a post-format replace or something similar:

```
System.out.print(String.format("%10s", "1").replace(' ', '#'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any number, like:

```
System.out.printf("%77s", "1");
```

You can do more formatting by using format method, like:

```
System.out.format("%4$2s %3$2s %2$2s %1$2s", "a", "b", "c", "d");
```

output: d  c  b  a

Comment: That will print 76 spaces and a digit 1, which is not what user1064918 was asking for.

Comment: Yes, @Jesper, I didn't mean the number of spaces. I meant the "character" to fill the empty space if the string is shorter than the specified length in the format.