# Right padding with zeros in Java

Tags: java, string-formatting, padding

Sorry if this question was made already, I've made a deep search and nothing.

Now, I know that:

```
String.format("%05d", price);
```

Will be padding my price with zeros to the left, so a price of 25 will result in **00025**

What if I want to pad them to the right, so the result is **25000**? How do I do that using **only** *String.format* patterns?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/388461/1374678

Comment: i've been there. there are some solutions. but none that does the job at once using only a pattern like the above

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You could use:

```
String.format("%-5s", price ).replace(' ', '0')
```

Can I do this using only the format pattern?

`String.format` uses `Formatter.justify` just like the `String.printf` method. 
From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997767/change-the-default-padding-character-in-java-printf) you will see that the output space is hard-coded, so using the `String.replace` is necessary.

Comment: got it, lets keep using the replace function than. thank you!

Comment: I don't think it is a good answer. It is not maintainable and generic. Using a reusable function is more proper.

Answer (score 9):

Try this :

```
String RightPaddedString = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.rightPad(InputString,NewStringlength,'paddingChar');
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try to read this doc, look if the library of apache commons [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) can help you

I've made a code like this :

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public static void main(String[] args)  {   
  String str = "123";
  str = StringUtils.leftPad(str,10,"0"); //you can also look the rightPad function.
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I solved this using only native Java.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("1234");
sb.setLength(9);
String test = sb.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "0");
System.out.println(test);
```

So it printed out : 123400000

Answer (score 1):

Credits to [beginnersbook.com](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/java-right-padding-a-string-with-spaces-and-zeros/), this is a working solution for the problem:

```
public class PadRightTest {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.out.println("#" + rightPadZeros("mystring", 10) + "@");
    System.out.println("#" + rightPadZeros("mystring", 15) + "@");
    System.out.println("#" + rightPadZeros("mystring", 20) + "@");
  }

  public static String rightPadZeros(String str, int num) {
    return String.format("%1$-" + num + "s", str).replace(' ', '0');
  }
}
```

and the output is:

```
#mystring00@
#mystring0000000@
#mystring000000000000@
```

Comment: This only works if your `str` doesn't already contain spaces

Answer (score 1):

Use this function for right padding.

```
private String rightPadding(String word, int length, char ch) {
   return (length > word.length()) ? rightPadding(word + ch, length, ch) : word;
}
```

how to use?

```
rightPadding("25", 5, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do without format or any function then used this simple trick
`System.out.println(price+"000");`

Comment: The OP has requested that it needs to be done using String.format pattern. This approach though solves the requirement but is not flexible. What is instead of 25000 the developer wants 2500 or 250000.