# Can SimpleDateFormat parse floating point seconds?

Tags: java, parsing, datetime

Is it possible to parse string `"00:00:01.2"` as 1 second 200 milliseconds?

But not as 1 second 2 milisecons, which is returned by

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS").parse()
```

Comment: Pad the string with zeroes before parsing it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962515/right-pad-with-zeros