# Java - Include decimal and preceding digits when setting length of double to be printed?

Tags: java, printf, double

I'm printing out a matrix, with each element having the same length printed on screen for easier reading.

If I do something like:

```
System.out.printf("%.16f", x);
```

then I get different lengths, depending on the preceding (whole) values:

```
x = 1;
x = 2.345;
x = 10;
x = 1243.5678;
```

gives the following outputs:

```
// 1.0000000000000000
// 2.3450000000000000
// 10.0000000000000000
// 1243.5678000000000000
```

which makes the matrix all messy. How can I limit the entire double - including the decimal and whole number - to a certain length? So, for the previous cases, the outputs would be:

```
// 1.0000000000000000
// 2.3450000000000000
// 10.000000000000000
// 1243.5678000000000
```

**Edit #1**

I don't want to just pad with zeros. Leading zeros are unattractive and can cause misreads. And even though I have `%.16f` right now, I may use less precision, and each digit will be significant (and non-zero).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right pad with zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962515/right-pad-with-zeros)

Comment: But what do you expect if you specify that you want 16 decimals? `%.16f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to format the output (but not exactly the same as your output):

1. Using `printf` method (assuming 21 digits width):

   ```
   System.out.printf("%21.16f%n", 1.0);
   System.out.printf("%21.16f%n", 2.345);
   System.out.printf("%21.16f%n", 10.0);
   System.out.printf("%21.16f", 1243.5678);
   ```

   => output

> 1.0000000000000000 
>            2.3450000000000000 
>        10.0000000000000000 
>    1243.5678000000000000

2. Use Apache Commons Lang library. Assuming you want to have 16 digits after the decimal point and 5 digits before it, the following might produce:

   ```
   System.out.println(StringUtils.rightPad(String.valueOf(1.0), 21, '0'));
   System.out.println(StringUtils.rightPad(String.valueOf(2.345), 21, '0'));
   System.out.println(StringUtils.rightPad(String.valueOf(10.0), 21, '0'));
   System.out.println(StringUtils.rightPad(String.valueOf(1243.5678), 21, '0'));
   ```

the output:

> 1.0000000000000000000 
>   2.3450000000000000000 
>   10.000000000000000000 
>   1243.5678000000000000

3. The other way is to use `DecimalFormat`:

   ```
   final String format = "00000.0000000000000000";
   DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(format);
   System.out.println(formatter.format(1.0));
   System.out.println(formatter.format(2.345));
   System.out.println(formatter.format(10.0));
   System.out.println(formatter.format(1243.5678));
   ```

   and the ouput:

> 00001.0000000000000000 
>   00002.3450000000000000 
>   00010.0000000000000000 
>   01243.5678000000000000

Comment: Printf can prefix zeros: System.out.printf("%021.16f%n", 1.0); Without looking it up this should print the number using at least 21 digits. From  most 16 are after the . and 5 before. When the number has more degits before the . the format is expanded...

Comment: @Matthias I know, but I thought the OP is not interested in the leading `0`s (see his desired output in the question). Anyway, thanks for the sugesstion.

Comment: Difficult to say who's solutions are better, but I really like the look of the first option you presented, with the decimals aligned. Much thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to chain two string formatting calls.  The first call is:

```
String.format("%.16f", x)
```

This will give an arbitrary width string representation of a float with 16 places of precision.  The next call should give a fixed width string of 18 characters which is right truncated, if necessary.

```
System.out.format("%18s : %s", String.format("%.16f", x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use BigDecimal for that.

Something like this:

```
BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(6, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

You can read more about it [here:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20int%29).

You can convert the above `Double` to `String` and then convert the String to BigDecimal.

You can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395281/convert-double-to-bigdecimal-and-set-bigdecimal-precision) for more details.