# How can you display 1 as 01 in java?

Tags: java

How can I display 1 as 01 in Java when using the g.drawstring command I have tried to look but I don't know what term I should use.

Comment: What kind of displaying? Printing in output, drawing on screen?

Comment: `int i = 1; g.drawString(String.format("%02d", i), x, y)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right padding with zeros in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962515/right-padding-with-zeros-in-java)

Comment: @jibbsie1802 eventhough saka1029 provided answer first in the comments, you can accept one of the answers so everyone will see that the question is closed

Answer (score 2):

You can format String and display it like this:

```
g.drawString(String.format("%02d", 1));
```

**%02d** is used for formatting, where 02 states for two digits with leading zero as necessary, and d - decimal number

Source: [Official Oracle Documentation on formatting numeric strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a string that contains that number, you can use [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

If you write something like `String.format("%02d", yourNumber)`, for `yourNumber=1` you will obtain the string `01`, so you can use the previous code in a System.out or draw it on screen.

If you want to use `g.drawstring`, you can use the following code:

```
g.drawString(String.format("%02d", yourNumber), x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Java's [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method, like this (recommended)

```
String.format("%02d", num)
```

Or if you could write something like this:

```
String text = (num < 10 ? "0" : "") + num;
```