# java printf with repeating periods

Tags: java, printf, string-formatting

We can use space to pad output to fit "fixed width columns" in java using printf. Example:

```
System.out.printf("%-30s - %s%n", "hello hello", "goodbye goodbye");
System.out.printf("%-30s - %s%n", "lots of cats",
        "large amounts of dogs");
System.out.printf("%-30s - %s%n", "a crowd of teachers", "no students");
System.out.printf("%-30s - %s%n", "three desks", "twenty boxes");
```

Gives output

```
hello hello                    - goodbye goodbye
lots of cats                   - large amounts of dogs
a crowd of teachers            - no students
three desks                    - twenty boxes
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
hello hello. . . . . . . . . . . goodbye goodbye
lots of cats . . . . . . . . . . large amounts of dogs
a crowd of teachers. . . . . . . no students
three desks. . . . . . . . . . . twenty boxes
```

or

```
hello hello..................... goodbye goodbye
lots of cats.................... large amounts of dogs
a crowd of teachers............. no students
three desks..................... twenty boxes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this has been attempted before [Change default padding character in java-printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997767/change-the-default-padding-character-in-java-printf). A workaround is suggested but and it may fit your scenario, although you could also maybe modify the java sourcecode, but I think everyone would strongly advise against that.

Comment: Fair enough.. so the answer is no it cannot be done without writing my own code. Oh well.

Comment: Correct however, you may have to get creative with it because of the fact you have spaces within your words